# Existence of a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm for a counting problem.

Tags: computational-complexity, open-problems, algorithms

Let T={1,...,n} be a set of tasks. Each task i has associated a non negative processing time p_i and a deadline d_i. A feasible schedule of the tasks consists of a permutation of n elements pi, such that \sum_i=1^k p_(pi(i)) <= d_(pi(i)) for all k=1,...n.

Does there exists a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm for computing the total number of feasible schedules?

A pseudo-polynomial time algorithm is an algorithm whose running time is bounded by a polynomial on the size of the input, given that the input is written in unary notation (2=II, 3 =III). (e.g., the size of a number n in unary notation is O(n), and not O(log(n)).

This is an open question from an article published in 2009 at Operations Research Letters.

Comment: Usually asking open problems is not really considered appropriate for MO; see the FAQ.  That said, you might ask something like "what is the current state of knowledge about this problem?"

Comment: Should the RHS read $d_{\pi(k)}$ instead of $d_{\pi(i)}$? I also agree with Daniel, it seems inappropriate to ask an open question (especially such a recent one) on MO.

Comment: At the time I write this comment, the question has been edited and now makes *no sense whatsoever*

Comment: I've rolled the question back to it's previous version, which at least made sense. I don't know anything about this question, but it seems perfectly reasonable to ask whether any progress has been made on it.

Comment: Actually, David, could you further roll it back to the version by Gerry, which had the same content but had grammar corrected and used LaTeX?

Comment: Your user name suggests that you are the author of the paper.  If this is the case, it seems that you reposted the same question on cstheory.stackexchange.com (http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/counting-complexity-of-a-scheduling-problem), removing the sentence that it was an open problem, according to Suresh Venkat.  In that case, I would like to let you know that I am still waiting for your explanation on this issue on the page I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to compute all solution for a specific instance, you could generate a an IP formulation of the problem and use a lattice point enumeration code such as http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~latte/">LattE. This might be a good problem for the  [operations research QA](http://www.or-exchange.com/)